# How to store extracted element via jsoup in database

Tags: java, mysql, jsoup

I'm using JSoup to extract element in `<table>` tag.This is the result when I use .text():

```
ACCOUNT
0000001
0000002
0000003

NAME
Customer1
Customer2
Customer3

BALANCE
100.00
200.00
550.00
```

I want to store this output into mysql database.Can I do that?what should I do if input to store is xml doc?

Answer (score 0):

When inserting XML into a database you need to consider what operations you'd like to perform on the data that the XML is representing.

You could, for example, consider the XML to be the input data and then create a schema that holds the data in an easily queryable manner. If that's what you'd like to do then use JAXB as the unmarshaller because you can easily generate suitably annotated pojos/entities from the XSD via the xjc tool. A bit of additional JPA annotating and you'll have a quick solution that maps the XML to a complete schema that allows a variety of mix and match queries and alternative views. Of course, JAXB annotations can be used to generate a wide variety of output formats (XML, JSON, YAML etc) so you're not limited to XML when you want to output this data.

Next, you could consider the XML to be the complete entity that you wish to store. In that case you want to store it either as a CLOB or as XML (in Oracle). Oracle certainly supports XPath based searches so you'd get a good opportunity for querying the resulting dataset.

Finally, if you're thinking that XML is too bloated, and you're in control of any resulting changes to the pojos you could serialize the unmarshalled pojos directly into the database as BLOBs. You'll have a fairly compact schema and database, but you'll suffer when it comes to querying since it's all gonna be binary. And you'll have binary version compatibility issues later on if you have to deserialize a very old dataset based on old pojos.

So, to summarise, JAXB is a very good way to handle the unmarshalling and later marshalling processes. It's quick and simple and (nod to @Blaise Doughan here) very well supported on SO for one thing. JPA is the technology of choice to perform your database operations. Hibernate is one implementer of JPA (with good extensions), and Spring supports it beautifully through the HibernateTemplate. Equally, you can use Spring's JpaTemplate which has, perhaps, a slightly shallower learning curve.